# Regroup button events in one event

Tags: c#, uwp

I use 6 different buttons doing practically the same thing.

```cs
private void VisaCreaDoc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.CREADOC);
}

private void VisaTravaux_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.TRAVAUX);

}

private void VisaRemiseOuvrageIR_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.REMISEOUVRIR);
}

private void VisaRemiseOuvrageExpl_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.REMISEOUVREXPL);
}

private void VisaMES_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.MISEENSERVICE);
}

private void VisaEncodageArchivage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.ENCODAGEARCHIVAGE);
```

As you can see, they're using a function from the `ViewModel` with a different parameter.

Is there any way to regroup the 6 button events to have only one and kind of pass the parameter directly in the XAML call or something similar to avoid having the "code duplication" ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you like it "better" but you can check which button was clicked inside the handler:

```
void HandleButton_Click(object sender, RoutetEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button b)
    {
        if (b == VisaCreaDoc) # VisaCreaDoc is the given name of your button instace in xaml
            ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.CREADOC);
        else if (b == VisaTravaux)
            ViewModel.ValidateItem(InfosPosteViewModel.TRAVAUX);
        else if (...) // etc.
    }
}
```

You can spice it up with a [switch pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements) to get rid of the `if / else if / else if / ...` chains.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't thought about that. Still a better solution than mine. Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can avoid some duplicate code by creating a command for the ViewModel function (see [Introduction to WPF Commands](https://wpf-tutorial.com/commands/introduction/)). As far as I know you can also define a `CommandParameter` in XAML.